# Как в github может быть рабочая ссылка на файл, а файл в репозитории отсутствует?

Tags: git, github

Есть репозиторий на github: https://github.com/chris1111/USB-3.0-NEC/ и в нем всего 2 текстовых файла.

В разделе релизов, по какой-то причине, автор не прикрепил готовый файл, а дал прямую ссылку на его скачивание: https://github.com/chris1111/USB-3.0-NEC/files/2694970/USB.3.0.NEC.zip

В репозитории нет папки /files и каких-либо архивов. Я мельком просмотрел все коммиты в веб интерфейсе github и там тоже не увидел этого .zip архива.

У меня не укладывается в голове. В теории, при переходе по ссылке на скачивание этого архива, должна быть ошибка 404, но скачивание происходит. Как это понимать?

Comment: Такая ссылка может быть при вставке файла в обсуждение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Похоже, что вы путаете git и github, а также URL и путь к файлу.

URL - это не путь. То, как сервер интерпретирует строку URL - это его внутреннее дело.

Для github, если URL имеет вид `https://github.com/<логин>/<репозиторий>/<xxx>/<yyy>`, то xxx - название раздела, в зависимости от которого yyy интерпретируется совершенно по-разному.

Некоторые примеры:

- releases/download - файлы, автоматически прикрепленные к релизу, указанному в yyy
- files - файлы, которые вручную залиты в github, но не в git.
- archive - это вообще не файлы. При обращении к такому URL будет сгенерирован архив, содержащий содержимое репозитория по указанному в yyy тегу.
- blob - найти (по указанной в yyy ветке/коммиту и имени) файл в git-репозитории, и вывести его в 
  просмотрщике github с подсветкой синтаксиса
- raw - найти (по указанной в yyy ветке/коммиту и имени) файл в git-репозитории, и вернуть его точное содержимое.

и так далее

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, теперь стало ясно. Git и Github я не путаю, просто думал, что по пути `https://github.com/<логин>/<репозиторий>/<другиепути>` должны располагаться другие файлы, находящиеся в репозитории. Сейчас посмотрел ссылку на URL для README, который лежит в корне и стало все ясно.

Answer (score 1):

Релизы можно [создавать вручную](https://help.github.com/en/articles/creating-releases) и вручную же загружать файлы, которые не будут отражаться в истории и вообще никак не связаны с гит-репозиторием.

Comment: У файла, ссылку на который дал автор репозитория, ссылка отличается от стандартной ссылки файла из релизной секции.

Вот, например, ссылка на релизный файл редактора Atom: https://github.com/atom/atom/releases/download/v1.40.1/atom-windows.zip, ссылка в моем посте другая.

Comment: @Drovosek, а вас не смущает наличие еще и вот такой ссылки https://github.com/chris1111/USB-3.0-NEC/archive/V1.zip ?

Comment: @ГерманБорисов нет, не смущает, потому что я могу найти через UI github'а, покопавшись буквально пару минут.